# How to convert file:// url to https or http url in react native expo using there package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to convert file:// url to https or http url in react native expo using there package? how can i do that? like in my case photo.uri is a file:// url and i want to convert it into a https or http url how can i? using expo-file-system,

i tried this:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { createDownloadResumable } from 'expo-file-system';

const { uri } = createDownloadResumable(photo.uri, FileSystem.documentDirectory);
let httpsUri = uri.replace("file://" "https://");
```

Also tried:
`const { uri } = createDownloadResumable(photo.uri, FileSystem.documentDirectory  + 'photo.jpg');`

NOTHING WORK

that uri becomes undefined

```
  const handleTakePicture = async () => {
    if (faceData.length === 0) {
      alert('No Face')
    }
    else if (cameraRef.current) {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
      console.log(photo.uri)
      if (!photo.cancelled) {
        const { uri } = createDownloadResumable(photo.uri, FileSystem.documentDirectory);
        let httpsUri = uri.replace("file://", "https://");
        console.log(`this is the url of the fs ${httpsUri}`)
      }
    }
  }
```

What can be a better solution?

Answer (score -1):

import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

```
// fileUri is a string that contains the file:// URL
const fileUri = 'file://path/to/file';

// Get the https:// or http:// URL of the file
const url = await Asset.fromUri(fileUri).downloadAsync();

console.log(url);
```

You will need to make sure that the file is available in the local file system by using fetch or XMLHttpRequest to download it.

Alternatively, you can use the react-native-fs package to convert file:// URL to https or http URL.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const fileUri = 'file://path/to/file';

const url = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + fileUri.substring(fileUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
console.log(url);
```

if you are using the react-native-fs package, you need to install it first by running npm install react-native-fs --save or yarn add react-native-fs in your project directory.

Comment: @M Ismail react-native-fs package is for rn cli it wont work on expo i am using expo how can i do that with expo-file-system'? also that photo.uri is the URL of the file name that i want to convert